# Style collection_radio_buttons in simple_form (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, tailwind-css

I received the code below of a simple_form for a multiple choice question's answers.

```
<%= simple_form_for :sent_activity, url: sent_activities_path(class_activity_id: @activity.id), method: :post do |f| %>
          <div class="flex-col inline-block items-center mr-4 my-5">
          <%= f.input :kind, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "multiple_choice" } %>
            <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :multiple_choice_answer, @activity.options, :last, :first do |b| %>
              <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
                <span class="flex items-center cursor-pointer text-md">
                  <%= b.label { b.radio_button + b.text } %>
                </span>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <div>
          <%= f.submit "Enviar", class: "bg-pink text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-lg" %>
        <% end %>
```

Now, I have to style the radio button and text inside the following line:

```
 <%= b.label { b.radio_button + b.text } %>
```

But I can't seem to find the proper syntax to style each of the components (the button and the text). For example, I want to insert some space between the button and the text but I didn't managed to do it inline.

I thought about styling the radio_button input in the css file but the problem is: there is already a style for this element that applies on another part of the application that is different from the one I should implement here.

What would be the best way to do it?
Is there a way to do it inline?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to style the radio button and the text inline is by using the label_html option for SimpleForm's collection_radio_buttons method. You can pass HTML attributes to the label_html option which allows you to style your radio button and text as you require. For example, if you wanted to add a margin between each radio button and its corresponding text, you could achieve this like this:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :multiple_choice_answer, @activity.options, :last, :first, label_html: { class: "margin-right-1" } do |b| %>


<div class="flex items-center mb-4">
    <span class="flex items-center cursor-pointer text-md">
      <%= b.label { b.radio_button + b.text } %>
    </span>
  </div>
```

< % end % >

Then, in your CSS file, you can define the margin-right-1 class:

.margin-right-1 {margin-right: 1rem;}

Comment: Hey @Richi4100! Thank you for taking the time.
Unfortunately, I did what you suggested and it didn't work for me. 
Nothing happened, actually.

Comment: Please fix code blocks formatting

Answer (score 0):

just had the same problem and i solved like below. I use tailwind as css framework.

```
<%= form.collection_radio_buttons :address, @addresses, :to_json, :label do |b| %>
        <div class="flex items-center my-2">
            <%= b.label class:'w-full flex items-center gap-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 p-3 rounded' do %>
                <%= b.radio_button class: 'text-primary focus:ring-transparent' %> <%= b.text %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

If you use a block you can split the complex component into it's elements and style or positioning them as you wish. In the end, just set the `class:''` argument on each element you want to style.

> It is to mention, that everything in the `b.label` component is clickable. This means if you make the parent `<div>` look like clickable it could lead to a bad user experience.

> This is also possible for the other collection fields like: `form.collection_check_boxes`

If you only want to style the elements, than you could **probably** use nested css like following and assign it to the form field directly without using the block. To get the correct structure just use the inspector (in my browser F12 key) r and see how the elements are nested.

```css
.your-class{
    .input{color: red}
}
```

But as i didn't try that my self, i can't provide a running example.